# Meteor - Collection Filter Implementation with Reactive Session Variables

Tags: meteor

Currently I have a meteor filter functionality working in following way.

- Publish the required data set from the server. This publication accepts parameters (parameters that are used for the filtering).
- In Client side, subscribe for this publication and pass in the parameters as reactive session variables.

> Meteor.subscribe('services', Session.get('Category'),
> Session.get('Name'));

- Again in the client I set the session variable when user changes the filter parameters and the subscription sends the new results as intended. Thanks to the reactivity of the Session variables.

> Session.set('Category', 'Shoes');
>
> Session.set('Name', 'Nike');

Is this approach the Meteor way of implementing this Use case or is there a better way ?

I don't want to publish the entire collection to client and then filter. My intention is to filter from server side and push only the filtered results to the client.

Comment: This is a pretty common pattern. Using [reactive variables](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var) also works well.